# Carriage return in QTextBrowser in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, carriage-return

I'm currently stuck. I'm trying to make it so that my `QTextBrowser` can do a nice presentation of the textfeed it gets(in multiple parts) from a programs output. But the download progress becomes several lines of text because i can't implement a way to handle carriage return. Here's a string that get's appended to my `QTextBrowser`, where `\r` and `\n` is shown:

> dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading thumbnail ...\n
>
> dQw4w9WgXcQ: Writing thumbnail to: D:\Musikk\DLs\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.jpg\n
>
> Destination: D:\Musikk\DLs\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.webm\n
>
> \r  0.9% of 3.33MiB at  4.03MiB/s ETA 00:00
>
> \r  1.8% of 3.33MiB at  3.62MiB/s ETA 00:00

And the last two lines there will be a lot of, since it's going to download all 100% of it and several files.

My current implementation was simple (and doesn't handle this issue), with

```
self.textBrowser.append(text)
```

And you'd get results like this (snippet of it all):

> dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading thumbnail ...
>
> dQw4w9WgXcQ: Writing thumbnail to: D:\Musikk\DLs\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.jpg
>
> Destination: D:\Musikk\DLs\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.webm
>
> 0.0% of 3.33MiB at 19.15KiB/s ETA 02:58
>
> 0.1% of 3.33MiB at 57.44KiB/s ETA 00:59
>
> 0.2% of 3.33MiB at 131.57KiB/s ETA 00:25

I could also remove the `\n` in the strings to have a smaller space between the lines where those are present.

I tried another partial solution for when the strings contain `\r`, instead of appending, however, some strings contain several `\r` characters, and this doesn't account for that.

```
        self.textbrowser.insertPlainText(text)
        if '\r' in text:
            self.textbrowser.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, mode=QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
            self.textbrowser.moveCursor(QTextCursor.StartOfLine, mode=QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
            self.textbrowser.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End,mode=QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
            self.textbrowser.textCursor().removeSelectedText()
            self.textbrowser.textCursor().deletePreviousChar()
```

I also tried:

```
        self.textbrowser.append(text) 
        self.textbrowser.textCursor().deletePreviousChar()
```

However it did remove some spaces between lines (removes the newline character .append() adds.) But it still doesn't really do anything but remove the \r character as if it wasn't there. And i can't at all get a consistent solution.

For reference, this is a wrapper for `youtube-dl.exe`.  And if you use youtube-dl.exe in console, (Powershell on Windows 10 for example) it'll do the right thing and jump to the start of the line when updating percentage, so you'll get a nice download line that increases by itself, and the ETA counts down with too, without going on over many lines.

For simplified code, here's an example that shows it in use, no other solution than appending the decoded string. Take note this is from a SO answer some time ago, where there's a `QTextEdit` instead of `QTextBrowser`. And it requires `youtube-dl.exe` to be in the working directory of the python script. In this case, the `QTextEdit` is called `self.edit`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QLabel, QLineEdit


class GUI(QProcess):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        # Create an instance variable here (of type QTextEdit)
        self.startBtn = QPushButton('OK')
        self.stopBtn = QPushButton('Cancel')

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.startBtn)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.stopBtn)

        self.label = QLabel("Url: ")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.EnableStart)

        self.hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.edit.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit Standard Output Redirection")

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)

        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)

        self.central = QWidget()

        self.central.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.central.show()

        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.startDownload)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.kill)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.slotChanged)

        self.EnableStart()

    def slotChanged(self, newState):
        if newState == QProcess.NotRunning:
            self.startBtn.setDisabled(False)
        elif newState == QProcess.Running:
            self.startBtn.setDisabled(True)

    def startDownload(self):
        self.start("youtube-dl", [self.lineEdit.text()])

    def readStdOutput(self):
        self.edit.append(str(self.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode('utf-8','ignore')))

    def EnableStart(self):
        self.startBtn.setDisabled(self.lineEdit.text() == "")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qProcess = GUI()

    qProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
    qProcess.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(qProcess.readStdOutput)

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't really know if this is doable, but to sum it all up:

- The strings appended to the QTextEdit does contain the newline characters and sometimes the carriage return character. (`\n` and `\r` respectively)
- The strings need to be appended without a new line, possibly as simple as removing the last newline character after appending.
- A few times, sentences get sent in one whole bunch so my second implementation doesn't work. Take note below to see, note that output is binary, because it hasn't been converted to string yet in this case. Printing the decoded stream below will give you the expected behavior in console. (But not in QTextEdit obviously)

> ```
> b'[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading webpage\n[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading video info webpage\n[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Extracting video information\n[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading MPD manifest\n[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading thumbnail ...\n'
>
> b'[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Writing thumbnail to: D:\\Musikk\\DLs\\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.jpg\n'
>
> b'[download] Destination: D:\\Musikk\\DLs\\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.webm\n'
>
> b'\r[download]   0.0% of 3.33MiB at 332.99KiB/s ETA 00:10\r[download]   0.1% of 3.33MiB at 856.39KiB/s ETA 00:03\r[download]   0.2% of 3.33MiB at  1.95MiB/s ETA 00:01 '
>
> b'\r[download]   0.4% of 3.33MiB at  4.18MiB/s ETA 00:00 '
>
> b'\r[download]   0.9% of 3.33MiB at  3.78MiB/s ETA 00:00 '
>
> b'\r[download]   1.8% of 3.33MiB at  4.24MiB/s ETA 00:00 '
>
> b'\r[download]   3.7% of 3.33MiB at  5.27MiB/s ETA 00:00 '
> ```

- I can get the wanted output in the python console simply by printing each string supplied by the function, and setting `end=''` because then it does heed the \r in the console. (Using PyCharm if it matters)

It a long and messy question, that boils down to, can i get the console functionality of `\r`, in this case, to work with `youtube-dl`, without extra lines/spaces, and without the percentages going over many many lines? I had a bit of critique for my last question, so i did my best to include attempts and observations through this.

Any help appreciated!

Edit on request, output in bytes, by changing `self.edit.append(...)` to

```
print(str(self.readAllStandardOutput()))
```

[image: byte output]

And here it is if i decode output, and print with

```
print(str(self.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode('utf-8','ignore')), end='')
```

[image]

Take note, this only shows one line because it updates every time a new string is provided.

Comment: Can you show how you want to get the output?

Comment: @eyllanesc Which output, the one in console, or the one in QTextEdit. IIRC you made the code example i posted here. (apart from where i decode the string output.)

Comment: You could take a screenshot to the console and place it in the post

Comment: @eyllanesc I added one image with raw output before it's decoded, just so you know how the strings looks with special characters, and what strings are provided each time. The second image shows how i expect the output to be in QTextEdit, but i'm using the console, as it does the right thing. You can see that there's only one line, and it continually updates as new strings are provided, since they don't contain any \n characters, but do have \r which causes lines to be replaced/'updated'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the **\n** at the end of each text we use `strip()`, then we must recognize the lines that have percentage and the substring `[download]`, this would suffice to solve the problem, but in several cases the input we get are Several lines in a single text, then what we need is the last line.

```
def readStdOutput(self):
    data = self.readAllStandardOutput().data()
    text = data.decode('utf-8','ignore').strip()

    # get the last line of QTextEdit
    self.edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
    self.edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.StartOfLine, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
    self.edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
    lastLine = self.edit.textCursor().selectedText()

    # Check if a percentage has already been placed.
    if "[download]" in lastLine and "%" in lastLine:
        self.edit.textCursor().removeSelectedText()
        self.edit.textCursor().deletePreviousChar()
        # Last line of text
        self.edit.append("[download] "+text.split("[download]")[-1])
    else:
        self.edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
        if "[download]" in text and "%" in text:
            # Last line of text
            self.edit.append("[download] "+text.split("[download]")[-1])
        else:
            self.edit.append(text)
```

Comment: This works great. Only issues is that it seems to remove the 100% sometimes. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Solved the 100% being removed. Not exactly sure what i did...  I think it was that i cleared the text selection on the second line in the else statement. (A line above the if statement in the else. )